# Python multithreading - main thread block socket.connect

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I have the following problem. I have few threads. There is main thread which only waits for termination call and threads-children which uploads files. Unfortunately children-threads are blocked when they want to connect with a specific server.
I use python2.7 on Linux.

The main thread contain this code:

```
    for i in xrange(n):
        upl = UploaderThread(self.user, self.password)
        upl.start()
    while threading.active_count() > 1:
        time.sleep(1000.)
```

And this is the fragment where the child-thread hang

```
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.settimeout(glob_timeout)
    #this fragment of code is accessed
    sock.connect( ("95.211.193.147", 8084 ) ) <- here the child-thread is blocked
    #this fragment of code is not accessed anymore
    sock.send(header)
```

What do I do wrong?

---

When I run few copies of the same program (every copy is one uploading thread) everything is ok. It means that server allows for multiple connections from one client.

Everything works when there is not main thread
i.e.
When I change the main thread in this way (removing waiting loop):

```
    for i in xrange(n):
        upl = UploaderThread(self.user, self.password)
        upl.start()
```

Then after death of main thread, every child thread works (is not blocked anymore).

When I try to connect with other server (not "95.211.193.147", 8084 ) then the children-threads are not blocked by main-thread.

I really don't understand what is going on.

---

definition of UploaderThread

```
class UploaderThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, user, password):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.uploader   = Uploader(user, password)
        self.daemon     = False

    def run(self):
        self.uploader.upload_dir()
```

and self.uploader.upload_dir() contains code snippet with connection to server.

Comment: If child-thread is executed one by one, maybe the socket server is not multithreading

Comment: The thing is, when I sue only one thread for uploading everything is ok. If more than every child-thread is blocked in that place.

When I remove main thread after starting children-threads then everything is ok. But I want to keep main thread.

Comment: Is this the GIL doing its thing? You're aware of how threading works in python, yes? Only one thread runs at a time, and the GIL yields control at certain times to different threads.

Comment: I think that GIl should do this. I'm using threading.Thread lib. But it looks like that when sock.connect is invoked then only main-thread have control.

Comment: It's not a problem at server side, that it will not allow more connections from the same client? Could you try the same code but run against different servers per thread? The code you show should work; the GIL won't prevent parallel IO, or cause deadlocks.

Comment: Please include the definition of `UploaderThread` as that's most likely the where we'll find the bug.

Comment: Interesting that it works when connecting to a different server. Is there something in the main thread that would block this particular server (like a file or DB lock) ?

Comment: Nothing :/ I use main thread only for catching ctr-c signal (and for dispatching children-threads). Nothing more.

Comment: Have you looked at using `multiprocessing`, and specifically the `Pool` class instead of `threading`? That would do away with all threading/GIL related headaches.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using the multiprocessing library instead of threading.  It has some limitations, but it sidesteps the GIL issues.